# New-AzWebAppSSLBinding - The specified network password is not correct

Tags: powershell, azure-automation, azure-appservice, powershell-7.0, powershell-7.2

I trying to Assign Already created SSL Lets Encrypt certificate to azure app service.
DNS zone in app service already configured to (1.test.webapp1)

```
$Site = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName "MyRG" -Name "webapp1"

New-AzWebAppSSLBinding `
    -Name "1.test.webapp1" `
    -WebApp $Site `
    -SslState SniEnabled `
    -CertificateFilePath "C:\Users\someuser\Downloads\*.test.webapp1.pfx" `
    -CertificatePassword 'password'
```

Error below:

[image]

I don't understand how I can put the password correctly

---

### UPD

Certificate generation output

```
Subject       : CN=*.test.webapp1
NotBefore     : 
NotAfter      : 
KeyLength     : 2048
Thumbprint    : 
AllSANs       : {*.test.webapp1}
CertFile      : C:website\cert.cer
KeyFile       : C:website\cert.key
ChainFile     : C:website\chain.cer
FullChainFile : C:website\fullchain.cer
PfxFile       : C:website\cert.pfx
PfxFullChain  : C:website\fullchain.pfx
PfxPass       : System.Security.SecureString
```

Comment: The "-CertificatePassword" switch is for the privatekey password of your certificate.
Did you put that in correctly ?

Comment: @LKo.exp Hi, I generating a certificate with the password "password", -CertificatePassword expected password as string, I don't know how I can insert password otherwise

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean. But let me explain.
With the cmdlet New-AzWebAppSSLBinding you try to bind an existing SSL certificate to an Azure Web App. You apparently have stored your already *existing* SSL certificate in the path "C:\Users\someuser\Downloads\*.test.webapp1.pfx".
So if you have an existing SSL certificate, you should usually have an private key password for your ssl certificate. This password you need to put in the "-CertificatePassword" paramenter. If you have no private key password, then let the paramter as an empty string. I hope it is now clear what you need to do

Comment: @LKo.exp I am generating let's Encrypt through module Posh-ACME
New-PACertificate -PfxPass "password", after creating I have output in UPD

As I understand you talk about KeyFile ?

Answer (score 0):

One of the workaround you can follow to resolve the above issue;

The password and the file path put them into a variable and provide your FQDN(Custom domain) for which you want SSL binding then you can use the moderated script as below.

**NOTE:-** *We can't able to test it due to some restriction in our subscription.*

***Make sure that your custom domain is verified as per the requirement and you must have the sufficient permissions to do this operation*** *as suggested here in* [***MS Q&A***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/192112/error-message-occurs-when-trying-to-upload-pfx-cer.html) by @*SnehaAgrawal-MSFT* .

```
$fqdn="<Replace with your custom domain name>"
$pfxPath="<Replace with path to your .PFX file>"
$pfxPassword="<Replace with your .PFX password>"
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName $webappname -ResourceGroupName $webappname -Name $fqdn `
-CertificateFilePath $pfxPath -CertificatePassword $pfxPassword -SslState SniEnabled
```

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT**|[***Bind a custom TLS/SSL certificate to a web app using PowerShell***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-configure-ssl-certificate) .
- **Blog**|[***To create .pfx certificate with password and config***](https://techdirectarchive.com/2022/03/18/how-to-generate-a-self-signed-certificate-and-export-in-pfx-format-via-powershell-part-2/).